# Hide div tag on page load

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, css

I have some div's in my project which has some animation on mouse-over done using java-script.
Now my problem is on page load i need to hide all the div's and display only title of the div,and on mouse-over of this title i should be able to make the div visible with all the animation done.

Below is my code:

```
<div id='Qhse' class="item user">
    <h2>qhse</h2>   
    <div id='qhse' class="qhse" runat="server" > 
    </div>
</div>

<div id='Policies' class="item home">
    <a href="#" class="icon"> </a>
    <h2>policies</h2>
    <div id='policies' class="policies" runat="server" > 
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#qhse{
      padding-top: 0.3em;
      padding-bottom:0.3em;
      background-color: #2C6D2C;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      vertical-align:middle; 

}

#policies{
      padding-top: 0.3em;
      padding-bottom:0.3em;
      background-color: #2C6D2C;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      vertical-align:middle; 

}
```

**JS**

```
$(function () {

    $('#nav > div').hover(function () {
        visibility: visible;
        var field = $('#<%= hdnSelected.ClientID %>');
        field.val(this.id);
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.find('div').stop().animate({
            'width': '100%',
            'height': '100%',
            'top': '-25px',
            'left': '-25px',
            'opacity': '1.0'

        }, 500, 'easeOutBack', function () {
        $(this).parent().find('ul').fadeIn(700);
    });

    $this.find('a:first,h2').addClass('active');
},
function () {

    var $this = $(this);
    $this.find('ul').fadeOut(500);
    $this.find('div').stop().animate({
        'width': '52px',
        'height': '52px',
        'top': '0px',
        'left': '0px',
        'opacity': '0.1',
        'visible': 'false'
    }, 5000, 'easeOutBack');

    $this.find('a:first,h2').removeClass('active');
});
});
```

Comment: where is `#nav` in your markup? Post the full markup.

Comment: The two div's is under a main div,its id is nav

Comment: Your code has many errors 1. `visibility: visible;` should be `'visibility': 'visible';`, and you cant write this directly - use `.css()`. 2. `'visible': 'false'` wont work. 3. there is no `<ul>` for `$this.find('ul')`.

Comment: Come to the point please. I just want to hide that div on page load and display it on mouse-over.

Comment: have you tried setting the css property: display to 'none' to hide it and 'block' to show it ?

Comment: @Lost, hover wont work on `display:none`. @Maes, how would hover work if the div's are hidden?

Comment: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r3y9x/)

Comment: Ya i did tried on css but i can't make it visible  on mouseover

Comment: Oh my bad didn't read the question correctly,

Comment: [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r3y9x/3/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a **[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shaun1ak/r3y9x/2/)**.

Added this to Document Ready.

```
$('#policies,#qhse').hide();
```

And following minor errors fixed.

- visibility: visible;
- 'visible': 'false'

Still not able to figure out where `<ul>` tags are. Hide,Hover works fine.

Comment: @Maes , Check again, I have modified the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

First, a bunch of remarks:

- There is no `#nav` in your HTML.
- `visibility: visible;` inside a function is not a valid JavaScript.
- `'#<%= hdnSelected.ClientID %>'` looks like you're generating your JavaScript using a server-side language. If you do, don't do it. If you don't (i.e. if it's some client-side template engine I've never seen before), make sure this line is doing what you expect it to do.
- Make sure `$this` variable is declared.
- What have you tried?

You already have your animation. What you want to do next is to show and hide elements. A [simple Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery%20show%20element) leads you to the jQuery function `show()`; similarly, there is a `hide()` function.

How can you apply those two functions to your actual code?

Comment: That is he problem i am facing. On mouse-over of one div other div should be hidden.